# Http Client e Async Task - ANDROID

Tags: java, android

Fala galera, gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar, 
sou novo no mobile estou começando com Android.
Estou fazendo uma requisição com HTTP CLIENT 
para me retornar todo o valor da página, seja web ou do meu
host local. Porem antes eu estava fazendo a chamada do meu
método que retornar esses dados (método q eu criei) , dentro da
função principal do onCreate(), porem isso apos alguns segundos,
se passar ai de 3 ou 5 segundos a requisição pode travar
então estou tentando utilizar a Async Task para executar
meu metodo que retorna o conteudo da requisição,
dentro do metodo doInBackground() da minha sub
classe PegaURL que está dentro da minha classe principal  MainActivity.

O problema que com meu emulador na versão 2.3.3 ou 2.3.1 ou 2.3 ele funciona perfeitamente,
porem ao rodar na versão 4.0 ou 4.4 ele abre a aplicação e ao clicar no botão para executar  o método o seguinte erro aparece: O My Application2 parou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já olhou no logcat??

Comment: Não.. eu fiz de uma forma diferente agora e parece que esta funcionando legal. Tirei esse meu metodo e coloquei o codigo dentro do doInBackground, e estuo dando execute pela instancia da classe que herda do Async Task, ate agora esta funcionando legal .